# how to match groups in regex?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Text on which I want to run regex-

```
2012-01-13 11:13:57 57 12.11.31.34 301 TCP_NC_MISS
```

When I run regex `(?<date>[^ ]+)` it matches date just fine. When I run regex `(?i)^[^ ]* (?P<time>[^ ]+)` it matches time just fine.

But when I combine my two regex as `(?<date>[^ ]+)(?i)^[^ ]* (?P<time>[^ ]+)` I don't get any grouping done. How should I go about fixing it so that I can get two groups- date and time?

Note that I text input is actually much more and I'll have many other grouping

Comment: If your text input is actually more, eventually you will get false matches. These are not the regular expressions to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date, time is nothing in regex,

you should parse this string for date, time.

`([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})`

first group is date, second group is time.

For example, this [link](http://regex101.com/r/vI8fC2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(?<date>) (?P<time>[^ ]+)` and take the first and thirt results.